# Blazor Server PageTitle access

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my blazor server pages I am using `<PageTitle>` to set the Page Title.

This Title renders correctly in the html `<title>` tag of the `<head>`.

Now I would like to be able to render the same Page Title string in my `NavMenu` component.

How do I access the currently set value of the `<PageTitle>` component?

Comment: Blazor Server or Blazor WASM?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

Implement a state container service like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service):

```
public class StateContainer
{
    private RenderFragment _title = (builder) => builder.AddContent(0, "App Name");

    public RenderFragment Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public event Action OnChange;

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

and register the service in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<StateContainer>();
```

Then create a `PageTitle` wrapper component that sets the page title and also update the title in the state container service.

`MyPageTitle.razor`:

```
@inject StateContainer State

<PageTitle>@ChildContent</PageTitle>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        State.Title = ChildContent;
    }
}
```

In your pages replace `<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>` with `<MyPageTitle>Counter</MyPageTitle>`.

Finally inside your `NavMenu` component inject the state container service and subscribe to the `OnChange` event.

```
@inject StateContainer State
@implements IDisposable

<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">@State.Title</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        State.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        State.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```